Find a Context Free Grammar (CFG) with 3p zeroes and 5q ones
How can I construct a context-free grammar for the following language?
The language is: $L = \{{(0 + 1)^* | \text{#}0 = 3p, \text{#}1 = 5q, p, q \geq 0} \}$.
I can construct a CFG for L if the zeroes and ones are grouped, such as strings of the form 000…11111…000…11111…. However, I’m struggling to create a grammar that works when zeroes and ones are mixed together, for example, 00101111.
My approach so far:

I define 2 production rules S → $A_0$ | $A_1$
$A_0$ is the start of generating zeroes.
$A_1$ is the start of generating ones.
For zeroes I use:
$A_0$ → $0B_0A_1$|ϵ
$B_0$ → $0C_0A_1$
$C_0$ → $0A_1$
For ones I use:
$A_1$ → $1B_1A_0$|ϵ
$B_1$ → $1C_1A_0$
$C_1$ → $1D_1A_0$
$D_1$ → $1E_1A_0$
$E_1$ → $1A_0$

This ensures that groups of three zeroes and five ones are generated, but there’s a problem. If I switch from generating zeroes to generating ones (or vice versa), I must immediately generate all three zeroes or five ones before switching back. This forces strings like 00011111 but doesn’t allow mixed strings like 00101111. How do I break the problem down so I can sort of keep count even If I mix the symbols?

Are $p$ and $q$ given, or does the language have strings with number of 0s and 1s a multiple of 3 and 5 respectively?

@HackR any p and q greater than zero

Then MJD's answer is perfect. Can you continue from that? Or would you like some details?

Hint 1: This language is actually regular. Do you know a theorem about grammars of regular languages?
Hint 2: have 15 nonterminals named $A_{0,0}\ A_{0,1}\ A_{0,2}\  A_{1,0}\ \dots\ A_{4,2}$ and use the nonterminals to
sort of keep count of both  symbols at the same time.

Which theorem? I know that regular languages are contained in CFG and that for any regular language, I could construct a DFA, so maybe a conversion from DFA to CFG? Is there any shorter way than 15 nonterminals?

Also, did you reason that it is regular because from the CFG, it is apparent we could construct a DFA, so it's regular? Or what logic did you use to determine it was regular?

The theorem I was thinking of is that a regular language can always be  represented by a right-regular grammar. If you don't know this theorem, that's OK, it's not important. But since you asked, the reason I knew this language was regular is because it's easy to imagine it recognized by a finite machine.  The machine only needs to count how many more zeroes and ones it needs to see to get to the next multiple of 3 or 5, and that's a finite amount of information. And the grammar you suggested below captures this intuition.

@MJD so something along these lines:
S → 0$A_{01}$ | 1$A_{10}$
$A_{01}$ → 0$A_{11}$ | $1A_{02}$
...
$A_{24}$ → 0$A_{04}$ | $1A_{20}$
So 3x5 = 15 states and the start state which is equivalent to $A_{00}$.
When I add a zero the left part of the subscript increases and for a one
I increase the right part of the subscript.

I would $S\to A_{00}$, because then it's more uniform, but sure.  Don't forget you need an $A_{??}\to\epsilon$ production somewhere.

Oh, and when you write this up, don't forget that $L$ includes the empty string!  Your grammar above doesn't generate $\epsilon$.
